# How do I create an interactive react web app that can be pre-compiled and served statically with gatsby?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, apache, gatsby

My school gives us a folder on our cs workstations that we can put html and python scripts in to be accessed from anywhere. I am using gatsby to create a react web app because it is a static site generator, but whenever I use 'gatsby build' and then move all of the files in the public directory into my public (school) folder, my app shows up but does not move (as if the state in the react components is not changing). Is it possible for gatsby to generate an html file with react's interactive functionality?

The way I understand static vs dynamic sites is that static sites do not need to fetch data from a server, the client just needs to be fed the html/css. However, static sites should still be able to 'change' in some way (ie different tabs or react animations). Is there something wrong with my understanding of how this works or does my problem lie in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: I think the site is non-interactive because it's loading the HTML file, but not the JS files needed for React. You need to use `gatsby serve` so that the linked JS files will load correctly.**

> Is it possible for gatsby to generate an html file with react's interactive functionality?

Yes. that's exactly what it does, actually. There is the `index.html` file that is generated for your root url (`/`).

Also, if you make a file like at `src/pages/about.js`, the build process will make a new file at `public/about/index.html` that can be accessed with the url `/about`.

Gatsby still makes fully functional React apps. You can still have components with state and effect hooks. Gatsby uses something called "React hydration", where the HTML kind of gives a 'starting point' for React to change things. From the [Gatsby docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvp2d.png):

> the browser can “pick up” where the server left off with the contents created by Gatsby in the /public folder and render the site in the browser like any other React app would.

---

> ...my app shows up but does not move (as if the state in the react components is not changing)

This was the tricky part to understand for me as well.

First, try opening the file as a plain old html file. That means opening Chrome and pressing `ctrl + o` on your keyboard. Don't open the file from your IDE.

The page will function as you described it, or maybe even worse. In my case, clicking the internal links gives a `file not found` error.

You'll notice something funny when you hover over the links:

[image: incorrect link location]

Here's the html code for that button:

```
<a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' href='/pre-checkout'>Register Now</a>
```

You see, Chrome gets confused and doesn't know I'm looking for a relative file location for that link. Rather than looking in the `public` directory where `index.html` lives, it looks for `C:/pre-checkout`.

If you open up the console, you'll see a bunch of similar errors caused by this problem:

[image]

**You see what's going on? Chrome is loading the page's HTML, but nothing else.**

Here's how the scripts look in the HTML file:

[image: index.html]

I'm using PyCharm as my IDE. Let's see what URL my browser goes to when I open the file:

[image: url in Firefox]

You see how the root url is the root of my project directory? The JS files live in the `public` directory, so it can't find them.

Running `gatsby serve` makes sure everything gets served from your `public` directory. That way you won't get these 404 errors.